# Item in Outliner is Incorrectly Organized And Can't Be Removed

Tags: outliner

There is an item in the outliner ( 3rd red box) that I have already organized into a folder (2nd red box). And I understand that it is under one parent object so it appears a second time (1st red box) and that's fine but the 3rd appearance of the item should not be there and can't be moved or removed. I mean i can disorganize and move it into another folder but i want it removed because it causes confusion. Why is it there and how do i remove the 3rd appearance (3rd red box). I've noticed it happens alot with other items as well.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit lost with your organisation but when you move a parent into a collection, its children stay in their current collection, it may be the problem here, so just move the child object in the same collection as its parent? Also an object can be part of several collections, if you right click and Unlink it will be removed from the collection but will stay in the other ones it is part of

Comment: ah cool, i tried this unlink before and it deleted what was in the 3D scene. but this time around it worked thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move a parent into a collection, but don't move its child, the child will stay in its current collection. Now if you want you can move the child in the same collection. Another thing is that an object can be part of several collections, if you right click and *Unlink* it will be removed from the collection but will stay in the other ones it is part of.